# Displaying images and text without any spaces

Tags: html

I'm trying to display the text beside the images. They are getting displayed but with spaces and they aren't beside each other. 
This is the code:

```
 .footer{
    font-family:Arial;
    background-color:white;
  }

 <div class=footer>Body Lab Gym © 2016
   <img src="icons/iconfb.png"><img src="icons/iconfb.png"  class="social">
   <img src="icons/iconfb.png">
   <img src="icons/iconfb.png">
   <img src="icons/iconfb.png"> Designed by:<br><br><br>
 </div>
```

and this is the result I get
[image]

Comment: add "vertical-align: middle;" to your logo CSS and crop the whitespace from your logo PNGs...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your icons have a lot of white or transparent space around the 'f' logo. Use an image editor to remove it.

Also, add a CSS rule `footer img { vertical-align: middle; }` to get your text and images on the same 'axis', i. e. vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the margins/padding to 0. Put each of them in the same class:

```
 <img class="noSpace" src="icons/iconfb.png"><img src="icons/iconfb.png"  class="social">
 <img class="noSpace" src="icons/iconfb.png">
 <img class="noSpace" src="icons/iconfb.png">
 <img class="noSpace" src="icons/iconfb.png"> Designed by:<br><br><br></div>
```

and use css to set the margins/padding to 0

```
.noSpace{
margins: 0 px;
padding: 0px;
}
```